# $A_5$ or the icosahedral group $I$ is not isomorphic to any subgroup of the binary icosahedral group $2I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quaternions, exact-sequence, group-extensions

I'm trying to show that the extension $1 \to \{\pm 1\} \to 2I \to I \to 1$ does not split. For that, I think it's sufficient to show that $I$ is not isomorphic to any subgroup of $2I$ (?). But I'm not sure how to because I could not find any explicit list of the elements of $I$.

Wikipedia gives a [list of the elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_icosahedral_group) of $2I$ in terms of quaternions but there is no Wikipedia page for $I$. I, however, know that $I \cong A_5$. So, at least, is there any direct way to show that $2I$ has no subgroup isomorphic to $A_5$? Say, we're given the list of elements of $2I$ in terms of quaternions.

Comment: $2I \cong {\rm SL}(2,5)$ has a unique element of order $2$, whereas $I \cong A_5$ has lots.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks! Do you have a reference that proves $2I \cong \mathrm{SL}(2, 5)$ and that it has an unique element of order $2$?

Comment: That can all be found on the wikipedia page you referred to.